# Cannot link shaders. ERROR:LINK-9 (line - 1) Missing main function for shade

Tags: qt, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am building simple "hello triangle" program to start with OpenGL-ES 2.0 developement, I am stuck with this tricky error. It displays that I can not link shaders. I have tested shader compilation on RenderMonkey and it is OK. But in my actual application it fails to link.

```
void COpenGLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    const size_t nMaxLength = 255;

    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0, 1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);


    char lpszVertexBuffer[][nMaxLength] =
    {
        "uniform mat4 g_MatViewProjection;\n",
        "attribute vec4 rm_Vertex;\n",
        "void main(void)\n",
        "{\n",
        "gl_Position = rm_Vertex;\n",
        "}"
    };

    char lpszFragmentBuffer[][nMaxLength] =
    {
        "precision mediump float; \n",
        "void main(void)\n",
        "{\n",
        "gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 );\n",
        "}\n"
    };

    m_nVertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    m_nPixelShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    int iVertexShaderLength = 6;
    int iPixelShaderLength = 5;

    glShaderSource(m_nVertexShader, 1, (const char**)lpszVertexBuffer, &iVertexShaderLength);
    glShaderSource(m_nPixelShader, 1, (const char**)lpszFragmentBuffer, &iPixelShaderLength);

    glCompileShader(m_nVertexShader);

    int iIsOk = 0;

    glGetShaderiv(m_nVertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &iIsOk);

    if(!iIsOk)
    {
        GLint infoLen = 0;

        glGetShaderiv(m_nVertexShader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLen);

        if(infoLen > 1)
        {
            char* infoLog = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * infoLen);

            glGetShaderInfoLog(m_nVertexShader, infoLen, NULL, infoLog);


            QMessageBox::warning(this, QString("Error"),
                                 QString(infoLog), QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::Cancel, QMessageBox::Yes);

            free(infoLog);
        }

        glDeleteShader(m_nVertexShader);

        return;
    }

    glCompileShader(m_nPixelShader);

    glGetShaderiv(m_nPixelShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &iIsOk);

    if(!iIsOk)
    {
        GLint infoLen = 0;

        glGetShaderiv(m_nPixelShader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLen);

        if(infoLen > 1)
        {
            char* infoLog = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * infoLen);

            glGetShaderInfoLog(m_nPixelShader, infoLen, NULL, infoLog);


            QMessageBox::warning(this, QString("Error"),
                                 QString(infoLog), QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::Cancel, QMessageBox::Yes);

            free(infoLog);
        }

        glDeleteShader(m_nPixelShader);

        return;
    }

    m_nProgram = glCreateProgram();

    glAttachShader(m_nProgram, m_nVertexShader);
    glAttachShader(m_nProgram, m_nPixelShader);

    glBindAttribLocation(m_nProgram, 0, "rm_Vertex");

    glLinkProgram(m_nProgram);

    glGetProgramiv(m_nProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &iIsOk);

    // Fail to pass status validation
    if(!iIsOk)
    {
        GLint infoLen = 0;

        glGetProgramiv(m_nProgram, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &infoLen);

        if(infoLen > 1)
        {
            char* infoLog = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * infoLen);

            glGetProgramInfoLog(m_nProgram, infoLen, NULL, infoLog);


            QMessageBox::warning(this, QString("Error"),
                                 QString(infoLog), QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::Cancel, QMessageBox::Yes);

            free(infoLog);
        }

        glDeleteProgram(m_nProgram);

        return;
    }

    glUseProgram(m_nProgram);

    connect(&m_Timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
    m_Timer.start(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the data structurs for the shader source code totally wrong. `glShaderSource` accepts an *array of pointers* to `char*`, so a sequence of strings. You store your shader source code in a 2-dimensional array `char`. Contrary to a somewhat common myth, arrays are not pointers in C/C++.

Furthermore, you are telling the GL that there is a *single* line with the length of 6 *characters* (5 for the fragment shader, respectively). The shader compiler only sees the very first part of your source code, and hence reports that it can't find a `main` function.

It is unclear why you even try to split your shader sources into several strings. You do not get any benefit from doing that as along as you don't recombine the different bits and pieces. I suggest you just use a singe string, so something line

```
const char *source=
    "uniform mat4 g_MatViewProjection;\n"
    "attribute vec4 rm_Vertex;\n"
    "void main(void)\n"
    "{\n"
    "gl_Position = rm_Vertex;\n"
    "}";
```

In C/C++, you can concatenate strings by simply writing them after each other, and this also works across lines.

THen, you can simply use the *address* of your `source` pointer and feed it into the GL:

```
glShaderSource(shaderName, 1, &source, NULL);
```

There is also no need to pre-calculate any lenghts, the GL will handle 0-terminated C strings just as well.

If you really want to go the route of different source strings, I strongly recommend you learn the basics of arrays, pointers, arrays of pointers and multidimensional arrays first.

Comment: I have not worked with GLSL until now, only with HLSL (Direct3D).